# Visualizing Orthogonal Vectors in 3D

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, 3d, orthogonality

I am in a multivariable calculus course. Let a be the vector <-1 ,1, c> (with c any number) and b the vector <1, 1, 0>. The two vectors are orthogonal, as the dot product of a and b is 0.
(The three positions of the vectors correspond with (i, j, k)).

I am trying to better understand the visualization of orthogonal vectors in three dimensions. Visually, why is it the case that the z-axis component of the vector a can be any number? I understand computationally that c times 0 will be zero. But I do not understand why the angle between a and b is $\frac\pi2$ regardless of the z-axis component of a. It makes sense to me visually that if c is 0, then <1,1,0> and <-1,1,0> would be orthogonal, but why does changing the z-axis component of a not change the angle between the vectors?

[For reference, here is <1,1,0>  and <-1, 1, 5>. How are these orthogonal?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LpW6.jpg)

Comment: $(1,1,0)$ is perpendicular to $(-1,1,0)$ in the plane. As you change $z$ from $0$ to any other value, you are rotating the second vector upward or down ward while maintaining the right angle between the two vectors.